# How do I change the functionality of an image slider which is part of ACF?

Tags: plugins, custom-field, advanced-custom-fields

I have an image slider on a page which was created as a Custom Field. The field type is called "Repeater", and each image automatically slides to the next. All I want to do is remove that automation and let the user click through the images themselves. I am not experienced with PHP, but I have some JavaScript knowledge. I'll include some code in the theme editor which looks related to the slider.

```
<div id="home-slider" class="home-page-slider swiper-container">
                    <div class="swiper-wrapper">
                        <?php if( have_rows('home_slider') ): ?>

                            <?php while( have_rows('home_slider') ): the_row(); 

                                // vars
                                $home_slider_image = get_sub_field('home_slider_image');
                                $home_slider_text = get_sub_field('home_slider_text');
                                $home_slider_link = get_sub_field('home_slider_link');
                                $home_slider_text_background_color = get_sub_field('home_slider_text_background_color');

                                ?>

                                <div class="swiper-slide">
                                    <?php if( $home_slider_link ): ?>
                                        <a href="<?php echo $home_slider_link; ?>">
                                    <?php endif; ?>
                                        <img src="<?php echo $home_slider_image; ?>" />
                                        <div class="h1-wrap">
                                            <h1><?php echo $home_slider_text; ?></h1>
                                        </div>

                                    <?php if( $home_slider_link ): ?>
                                        </a>
                                    <?php endif; ?>
                                </div>

                            <?php endwhile; ?>
                        <?php endif; ?>
                    </div>
                    <div class="swiper-pagination"></div>
                    <!-- Add Arrows -->
                    <div class="swiper-button-prev"></div>
                    <div class="swiper-button-next"></div>
```

I'm out of my depth here and wish I could post the most relevant code or be hyper specific about the problem, so please inform me on if I can help find more pertinent information to help here.

Comment: You will have to find the javascript-library that is used for the "sliding" part of the slider. The Plugin will probably have an initialization script. If you are lucky, the plugin developer has put some filters in there. However, that is nothing that can be said with the markup you provided. Please edit your question to include the initialization script.

Comment: Hi, welcome to [wordpress.se]. As a rule, the community considers questions about third-party plugins off-topic. You might be better off directing this question to the support page for ACF. You can find out what questions are a good fit [here](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: Hi, thanks for the comments. I found the code in the scripts.js file in the theme editor. The dev was using SwiperAPI and it had nothing to do with ACF.